# Elimination of Aspx pages during Publish

Tags: asp.net, .net

I need to eliminate .apsx pages for  my application for different locations basically.
How can I eliminate those pages during Publish time?
I have seen  by making pages  to Build Content to none. Is there any other alternate
solution?

Regards,

Sachin K

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Web deployment project](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24509) and follow these steps:

1. Add your WDP (web deployment project).
2. Right click on it and click on Open Project File.
3. in the wdproj file you will see a tag called `<ItemGroup>`.
4. Inside this tag add the following line:

   ```xml
   <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\FolderName\**\*.*" />
   ```
5. Save and close your wdproj file and that’s it.

Comment: Hi Ali,
Which tag I need to add?

Comment: I fixed the formatting. XML doesn't render unless you surround it with backticks

Comment: @EoinCampbell true, but indenting it with spaces is even better as it kicks the code prettify into action.

Comment: @Ali without proper formatting, HTML tags get hidden in the post so sachin saw "in the wdproj file you will see a tag called" without any tag. For inline code format use backticks for whole line or lines indent with spaces - see the edits of your post.